# Копировать, удалять и вставлять в активный textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

В программе несколько textbox'ов. При попытке копировать данные с одного бокса и вставки в другой, программа все равно вставляет данные с буфера обмена в тот бокс, откуда скопировал и игнорирует активный бокс, в который нужно было вставить. Как исправить проблему?

Добавлю, что проблема происходит, если пользоваться горячими клавишами. Через правую кнопку мыши, все работает. Функция "ShortcutsEnabled" тоже у всех активно.

Comment: не смог воспроизвести. При переходе в новый текстбокс что табом, что мышкой, все работает корректно. Проверяйте обработчики событий и захват фокуса, скорее всего у вас тот бокс в который вы собираетесь вставить все таки не активен.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте правильность указания TextBox'ов(если вы программно копируете и вставляете), если это делается вручную,посредством CTRL+C CTRL+V есть вероятность, что программа фокусируется на одном и том же TextBox. В этом случае проверьте свойства TextBox